# Why do I randomly get "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }" prepended to text pasted from another program?

Tags: clipboard, paste

This has been affecting me for at least 4 years, if not longer, across various versions of Ubuntu and Linux Mint, with many different clipboard manager configurations running as well (if that changes things, which I doubt). I'm currently using Ubuntu GNOME 14.10.

At random times (so I can't predict *when* or *why* this happens), but very often, text I copy from one program and paste into another will turn up with the plaintext CSS

```
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

before it, surrounded by several spaces on both sides.

Sometimes there is a two- or three-second pause between when I enter the command to paste the text in and when the text + CSS is added. Sometimes the text shows up instantly, but the CSS is added two or three seconds later!

Google searching for this phrase just turns up web pages that happen to use this CSS, usually foreign language dictionary sites for whatever reason.

What's going on? Thanks.